# Не работает проверка на существование записи (PHP PDO MySQL)

Tags: php, mysql, запрос, pdo

Help me, plz!  Again.

Добавляю в базу записи. Значения полей должны быть уникальными в таблице. Проверяю перед добавлением в базу, нет ли уже записи с таким значением.

Если прописать в phpmyadmin

```
SELECT COUNT( 1 ) 
FROM `cities` 
WHERE `city_name` = 'город, который уже есть в базе';
```

В ответ получаю столбец COUNT(1) со значением 1;

Если запустить код с картинки

```
var_dump($repeat->fetchColumn()); выдает string(1) "0"
```

Запуская скрипт, получаю ошибку Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry. Такая запись уже есть... Понятно почему.

Как исправить?

```
    for($i = 0; $i < count($data); $i++){
    for($j = 0; $j < count($data[$i]); $j++){
        for($k = 0; $k < (count($data[$i][$j])/4); $k++){
                $repeat = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `cities` WHERE `city_name` = ':city_name';");
                $repeat->bindParam(':city_name', $data[$i][$j]['title']);
                if($repeat->execute()) {
                    var_dump($repeat->fetchColumn()); // string(1) "0" 
                    if ($repeat->fetchColumn()==0){
                        $stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `p368133_student`.`cities` (`city_id`, `city_name`, `cid`) VALUES (NULL, :city_name, :cid);");
```

Comment: Не надо вообще проверять перед вставкой. используйте `insert ... on duplicate key update cid=cid`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `cities` WHERE `city_name` =
>   ':city_name';");

Но

> VALUES (NULL, :city_name, :cid);")

Кавычки для строкового литерала `PDO` добавляет сам. Поэтому подстановщик для `insert` у вас написан верно, без кавычек. А запрос проверки - кавычек получается второй комплект. Города, название которого обрамлено в кавычки, у вас, очевидно, нет. Поэтому count даёт 0 записей.

Правильно будет не писать кавычки.

```
$repeat = $conn->prepare("SELECT COUNT(1) FROM `cities` 
     WHERE `city_name` = :city_name");
```

---

Кстати, `prepare` в цикле вызывать не надо. Перенесите его до цикла и просто вызывайте `execute` в цикле. Для этого изначально механизм подготовленных выражений и был сделан, чтобы повторяющиеся запросы подготавливать один раз и использовать несколько раз.